# Area of Square - Comparing squares

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is:

> > If the area of a parallelogram $JKLM$ is $n$ and if length of $KN$ is $n+(1/n)$, then find the length of $JM$. (The answer is $n^2 /( n^2+1 )$.)

[image]

How would i go about solving this problem ?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the area of a parallelogramm?

Comment: Formula is : lxW

Comment: And how are $l$ and $W$ in $l \times W$ expressed in terms of your points $K, L, J, N, M$=

Comment: I tried applying Pythagoras formula to triangle to obtain the hypotenuse. and then insert that value in area of parallelogram to obtain the other side but it doesn't work.

Comment: why would you need the hypotenuse? That's not in the area calculation anywhere.

Comment: I find the question rather strange: $n$ has the dimension of area, so what dimension does $n+1/n$ have? Nothing sensible, and certianly not length.

Comment: Thats a standardized test question .. A lot of their questions don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [area of a parallelogram](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol1/area_parallelogram.html) (or see [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Area_formulas)) is the base times the height. The base here is $JM$ and the height is $KN$, so the area is $$KN * JM = n$$

So you have

$$
\left(n + \frac{1}{n}\right)*JM = n
$$
Then you solve for $JM$

Comment: I like this method.. How did you get the formula for the Area ? KN * JM (KN is the height) . Isnt the Area of a Prarallelogram L x W or ( JK x JM)

Comment: @Rajeshwar: It is the formula for the area of a parallelogram. You can for example see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Area_formulas

Comment: @Rajeshwar: So in general the area of a parallelogram is the base times height. Your base is $JM$, the height is $KM$, so the area is the product $JM*KN$.